# MongoDB not responding to Java Client

Tags: java, mongodb, driver, connection-timeout

I have mongodb running on Linux 7. Java client from a remote system tries using Driver 3.0.2 to connect to it using code as shown below:

```
 mongoClient = new MongoClient(new ServerAddress("10.12.22.22", 27017),
                               new MongoClientOptions.Builder().connectTimeout(300000).socketTimeout(300000).build());
```

The result is the following exception:

```
**INFO: Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server 10.12.22.22:27017
com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket**
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:63)
    at com.mongodb.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:114)
    at com.mongodb.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:127)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.waitForConnect(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:85)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:345)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:206)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:188)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:172)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:392)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStreamHelper.initialize(SocketStreamHelper.java:50)
    at com.mongodb.connection.SocketStream.open(SocketStream.java:58)
    ... 3 more
```

Java Client running on windows: 10.12.22.116
Mongo DB running on Linux: 10.12.22.22: 27017

When the Java client is executed, `tcpdump` on linux system clearly shows packets reaching mongo db process but still no response from db.

```
[root@localhost ~]# tcpdump -i enp0s3 port 27017 -vv

tcpdump: listening on enp0s3, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 65535 bytes00:22:40.026816 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 8435, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.12.22.116.12364 > 10.12.22.22.27017: Flags [S], cksum 0xdd04 (correct), seq 1967333969, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
00:22:43.026954 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 8437, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 52)
    10.12.22.116.12364 > 10.12.22.22.27017: Flags [S], cksum 0xdd04 (correct), seq 1967333969, win 8192, options [mss 1460,nop,wscale 8,nop,nop,sackOK], length 0
00:22:49.028216 IP (tos 0x0, ttl 128, id 8439, offset 0, flags [DF], proto TCP (6), length 48)
```

MongodB is listening at target port as shown below:

```
[root@localhost ~]# netstat -tunlep

Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       User       Inode      PID/Program name    
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:25            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      0          20288      2360/master         
tcp        0      0 10.12.22.22:27017       0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       27947      3220/mongod**         
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:27017         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      1001       27945      3220/mongod
```

There is no firewall active as well (checked using `iptables -L -n`)

Please see what is missing here which is causing this issue?

Comment: We welcome you on SO. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: There is something rather strange, since two instances of mongod seem to be bound on different IPs, but the same port. Please add the result of `ps axu | grep [m]ongod` and the content of your mongod.conf. Furthermore, what is the result of `telnet 10.12.22.22 27017` when executed on the client? As a side node: postfix should not be run as root, iirc.

Comment: Result of 'ps axu | grep [m]ongod' is :ps axu | grep [m]ongod                  

ultrama+  3220  0.3  7.1 657260 72764 pts/0    Sl   Aug10   0:35 mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf

Two ips are shown because in mongo.conf I have mentioned two ips as I need to connect remotely from Java client :
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1,10.12.22.22
   port: 27017

Comment: Full conf is:

[root@localhost ~]# cat /etc/mongod.conf 

processManagement:
   fork: false
net:
   bindIp: 127.0.0.1,10.12.22.22
   port: 27017
storage:
   dbPath: /data/db
systemLog:
   destination: file
   path: "/var/log/mongodb/mongod.log"
   logAppend: true
   component:
      network:
        verbosity: 5
storage:
   journal:
      enabled: true

Answer (score 1):

Finally it comes out that Linux firewall was blocking it. I disabled it using

```
service iptables stop
```